# Media Foundation (EVR) on Multiple Screens

Tags: c#, windows, directshow, ms-media-foundation, directshow.net

I am now writing a Windows Form application (C#.Net) using media foundation (more precisely, EVR) to display the output of a USB camera to the screen.

Normally it works fine. However, if I run on a Windows having multiple screen, the Windows showing the camera output will be shown as black if the window is moved from the primary screen to the secondary screen.

E.g. if the Window is 60% in the primary screen and 40% in the secondary screen, the output shows normally. If the Window is 60% in the secondary screen and 40% in the primary screen, it shows as black.

My sample code for initializing the EVR engine is similar as follows:

```
private IMFActivate pActive = null;
private object objVideoSink = null, objVideoRenderer = null, objVideoDisplayControl = null;
private IMFMediaSink pVideoSink = null;
private IMFVideoRenderer pVideoRenderer = null;
private IMFVideoDisplayControl pVideoDisplayControl = null;
private IMFStreamSink pStreamSink = null;
private IMFMediaTypeHandler pSinkMediaTypeHandler = null;
private int sinkMediaTypeCount = 0;
private IMFMediaType pVideoOutType = null;
private IMFMediaEventGenerator pEventGenerator = null, pstreamSinkEventGenerator = null;
private SecureConference.AV.MediaEventHandler mediaEvtHandler = null, streamSinkMediaEvtHandler = null;
private IMFVideoSampleAllocator pVideoSampleAllocator = null;
private object objVideoSampleAllocator = null, objD3DManager = null;
private IMFSample pD3DVideoSample = null;
private IMFMediaBuffer pDstBuffer = null;
private IMF2DBuffer p2DBuffer = null;
private IMFPresentationClock pClock = null;
private IMFPresentationTimeSource pTimeSource = null;

private void Init()
{
    HResult hr = MFExtern.MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(this.Handle, out pActive);
    hr = pActive.ActivateObject(typeof(IMFMediaSink).GUID, out objVideoSink);
    pVideoSink = (IMFMediaSink)objVideoSink;
    hr = MFExtern.MFGetService(
        pVideoSink,
        MFServices.MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE,
        typeof(IMFVideoRenderer).GUID,
        out objVideoRenderer
        );
    pVideoRenderer = (IMFVideoRenderer)objVideoRenderer;
    hr = pVideoRenderer.InitializeRenderer(null, null);
    
    hr = MFExtern.MFGetService(
        pVideoSink,
        MFServices.MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE,
        typeof(IMFVideoDisplayControl).GUID,
        out objVideoDisplayControl
        );
    pVideoDisplayControl = objVideoDisplayControl as IMFVideoDisplayControl;
    hr = pVideoDisplayControl.SetVideoWindow(this.Handle);
    hr = pVideoDisplayControl.SetVideoPosition(null, new MediaFoundation.Misc.MFRect(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
    
    hr = pVideoSink.GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, out pStreamSink);
    hr = pStreamSink.GetMediaTypeHandler(out pSinkMediaTypeHandler);
    hr = pSinkMediaTypeHandler.GetMediaTypeCount(out sinkMediaTypeCount);
    
    hr = MFExtern.MFCreateMediaType(out pVideoOutType);
    hr = pVideoOutType.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType.Video);
    hr = pVideoOutType.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFMediaType.RGB32);
    hr = pVideoOutType.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, 2);
    hr = pVideoOutType.SetUINT32(MediaFoundation.MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, 1);
    // to be adjusted
    hr = SetMFSize(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    //hr = SetMFSize(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, this.Width, this.Height);
    hr = SetMFSize(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, miImageWidth, miImageHeight);
    //hr = pVideoOutType.SetUINT64(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 4294967297);
    //hr = pVideoOutType.SetUINT64(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 2748779069920);
    
    hr = pSinkMediaTypeHandler.SetCurrentMediaType(pVideoOutType);
    
    mediaEvtHandler = new MediaEventHandler();
    streamSinkMediaEvtHandler = new MediaEventHandler();
    //hr = MFExtern.MFGetService(
    //   pVideoSink,
    //   MFServices.sink,
    //   typeof(IMFMediaEventGenerator).GUID,
    //   out objEventGenerator
    //   );
    //pEventGenerator = (IMFMediaEventGenerator)objEventGenerator;
    pEventGenerator = (IMFMediaEventGenerator)pVideoSink;
    hr = pEventGenerator.BeginGetEvent(mediaEvtHandler, pEventGenerator);
    
    pstreamSinkEventGenerator = (IMFMediaEventGenerator)pStreamSink;
    hr = pstreamSinkEventGenerator.BeginGetEvent(streamSinkMediaEvtHandler, pstreamSinkEventGenerator);
    
    hr = MFExtern.MFGetService(
        pStreamSink,
        MFServices.MR_VIDEO_ACCELERATION_SERVICE,
        typeof(IMFVideoSampleAllocator).GUID,
        out objVideoSampleAllocator
        );
    pVideoSampleAllocator = (IMFVideoSampleAllocator)objVideoSampleAllocator;
    hr = MFExtern.MFGetService(
        pVideoSink,
        MFServices.MR_VIDEO_ACCELERATION_SERVICE,
        Guid.Parse("a0cade0f-06d5-4cf4-a1c7-f3cdd725aa75"),
        out objD3DManager
        );
    
    hr = pVideoSampleAllocator.SetDirectXManager(objD3DManager);
    hr = pVideoSampleAllocator.InitializeSampleAllocator(1, pVideoOutType);
    hr = pVideoSampleAllocator.AllocateSample(out pD3DVideoSample);
    hr = pD3DVideoSample.GetBufferByIndex(0, out pDstBuffer);
    p2DBuffer = (IMF2DBuffer)pDstBuffer;
    
    hr = MFExtern.MFCreatePresentationClock(out pClock);
    hr = MFExtern.MFCreateSystemTimeSource(out pTimeSource);
    hr = pClock.SetTimeSource(pTimeSource);
    pVideoSink.SetPresentationClock(pClock);
    pClock.Start(0);
}

// and once I received a bitmap (bmp2), I put it to the engine:

private void SetBitmap(Bitmap bmp2, long timestamp)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height);
    BitmapData bd = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
    bitmapBuffer = bd.Scan0;
    int bitmapBufferLength = 4 * bmp2.Width * bmp2.Height;
    HResult hr = HResult.S_OK;
    
    if (!(bmp2.Width == miImageWidth && bmp2.Height == miImageHeight))
    {
        miImageWidth = bmp2.Width;
        miImageHeight = bmp2.Height;
        hr = SetMFSize(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, miImageWidth, miImageHeight);
    }
    
    if (mlStartTimestamp == 0)
    {
        mlStartTimestamp = timestamp;
        hr = pD3DVideoSample.SetSampleTime(0);
    }
    else
    {
    
        hr = pD3DVideoSample.SetSampleTime(timestamp - mlStartTimestamp);
    }
    hr = pD3DVideoSample.SetSampleDuration(sampleDuration);
    hr = p2DBuffer.ContiguousCopyFrom(bitmapBuffer, bitmapBufferLength);
    
    hr = pD3DVideoSample.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MFSampleExtension_FrameCorruption, 0);
    if (bitmapCount > 0)
    {
            hr = pD3DVideoSample.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity, 0);
    }
    hr = pD3DVideoSample.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint, 1);
    
    hr = pStreamSink.ProcessSample(pD3DVideoSample);
    
    bmp2.UnlockBits(bd);
}
```

How can I solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tried the sample MFVideoEVRWebCam from https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples and it has the same problem, too! My code is similar to this project.

Comment: This is, generally speaking, behavior by design: you are only guaranteed to have video visible on the monitor which hosts the biggest fraction or the monitor you explicitly point to (VMR-7 and VMR-9 though, not EVR). If you need video to span across multiple monitors reliably, you will have to split video yourself and display via several renderers.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. If I could somehow switch the screen EVR goes black on, that'd solve my issue, but I don't even know why it goes black, let alone flipping the situation.

Comment: @RomanR. What do you mean by splitting and how to configure the renderers for a different monitor?

Comment: @Linus Did you manage to solve this issue? From what I understand not using EVR in the first place seems to be the only possible way.

Comment: @Javid. I haven't solve the issue. I tried to use PictureBox to display video instead of EVR. However, some of my other threads are time-dependent and using PictureBox seems to use up some of the PC's resources, thus affects the time-dependent threads. Therefore, I keep on using EVR but just notify users that only primary screen works.

Comment: @Javid I have found another alternative for solving this problem. Rather than using PictureBox, we can use Graphics.DrawImage to draw the images of a video stream. Although it is worse than EVR (consuming more resources), it is better than PictureBox anyway.

Comment: @Linus I'm using a similar approach right now. I'm using BitmapSource in WPF